# Convergence of binary sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I have given a sequence  $x_n $ such that $x_1=0.1$ , $x_2=0.101$ , $x_3=0.101001..... $
Does this sequence converge?
In my opinion it is a divergent one but I am not quite sure. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it converges. It is increasing and all terms are less than $1$ (bounded)

Comment: Okay I got it then it's limit is either rational or irrational number.which one it should be?

Comment: It limit is the series $\sum 2^{-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$. It doesn't seem that it is rational, but I'm not sure. All I can find about it is [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%3D1+to+infinity+of+2%5E(-(n(n%2B1))%2F2))

Comment: It is transcendental.  In fact, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{n(n+1)}$ is transcendental for all algebraic numbers $q$ with $0 <|q|<1$.  See [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195510210) of Duverney, Nishioka, Nishioka and Shiokawa.

Comment: That's a very good reference (easy to understand) to prove limit cannot be rational (and more than that). Also I realized that I'm not sure whether your "binary sequence" is written in base $2$ or in base $10$. If it is written in base 10, then you should replace $2$ with $10$ in what I said, and everything still holds.

Answer (score 0):

It is a convergent sequence, if you use the definition of convergence or if you see that sequence is bounded monotonic increasing. It converges to an irrational number since the sequence is non repeating and non terminating.